# If $P(b\mid a) >P(b)$ and $P(a)>0$ then $P(\neg a \cap \neg b)>P(\neg a)\cdot P(\neg b)$

Tags: probability-theory

I tried to break the conditional probability down and also substitute $P(a) = 1 - P(\neg a)$, however, I wouldn't get what I want. I am struggling with this question and I don't know how should I approach it.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by noticing that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(B|A) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(B\cap A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)} > \mathbb{P}(B) \Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{P}(B\cap A) > \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)
\end{align*}

Then we may approach the second part as follows:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B^{c}) - \mathbb{P}(A^{c})\mathbb{P}(B^{c}) & = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A\cup B) - (1 - \mathbb{P}(A))(1 - \mathbb{P}(B))\\\\
& = -\mathbb{P}(A\cup B) + \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B)- \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) - \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) > 0
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!